# Proving solutions to the anisotropic kepler system that meet certain constraints lie on the position axes of configuration space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, mathematical-astronomy

The system is:
  \begin{equation*}
  x''=\frac{-\mu x}{(\mu x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}
  \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
  y''=\frac{-y}{(\mu x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}
  \end{equation*}
With $\mu>1$ a constant adding anisotropy to the otherwise newtonian system. 
With energy function:
\begin{equation*}
  E: \mathbb{R}^4:\rightarrow \mathbb{R}
  \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
  (v_{x},v_{y},x,y)\mapsto \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{v_{x}^2+v_{y}^2}-
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu x^{2}+y^{2}}}
  \end{equation*}
Which I have reparametrized, reducing the velocity dimension to 1 in order to plot level curves in configuration space (for only negative values of energy) as:
  \begin{equation*}
  E(V,x,y)=\frac{|V|^2}{2}-
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu x^{2}+y^{2}}}
  \end{equation*}
Squaring the norm of velocity for smoothness (I believe).

The constraints on the solution that i must prove lies on the $x$ or $y$ axes of configuration space are twofold:
1. Solution must meet the $V=0$ curve and;
2. The solution must be a straight-line collision ejection orbit.

I believe the first condition implies that, after solving the $E$ funciton for $\frac{|V|^2}{2}$ and setting to zero implies: 
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{\mu x^2+y^2}=\frac{-1}{h}
\end{equation*}

My trouble is with the second condition as I am not quite sure what it means (particularly the "straight-line" portion, which was not defined) but from what i have gathered from Hirsch-Smale and Devaney chapter 13.4, this means that evaluating the limit as $x\rightarrow 0$ means $y\rightarrow \infty$ and the same for $y\rightarrow 0$ and $x\rightarrow \infty$ or solutions go to infinity in finite time in both directions. I think this then should imply that solutions "lie on" the x and y axes. Velocity or the z direction has been set to zero and we are sending either coordinate to 0, yielding a one dimensional explosion along one of the two position coordinates in configuration space. Does this make sense? Any clarification or resources on the meaning of condition 2 would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the level sets of the function $E_1(V,x,y) = \frac{|V|}{2} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu x^2+y^2}}$ do not coincide with the level sets of the function $E_2(V,x,y) = \frac{|V|^2}{2} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu x^2+y^2}}$, because $E_1$ and $E_2$ are not the same function.

Secondly, the first energy function you defined is not conserved by the system, as
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\text{d}E_1}{\text{d} t} = \frac{\mu x x' + y y'}{(\mu x^2 + y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}}\right) \neq 0.
\end{equation}
However, $E_2$ *is* conserved, yielding a proper energy function for the system.

Thirdly, the condition that the solution you seek **meets** the $V=0$-curve is not equivalent with the condition that it **entirely coincides** with the $V=0$-curve, which is what you assumed.

Forthly, the solution **being** a 'straight line collision orbit' is highly coordinate dependent. I assume (and rightly so, I believe) that your $x$ and $y$ axes are the Cartesian coordinate axes for the physical system. In those coordinates, a straight line obeys the relation $y = a x + b$. Assuming that the collision should be with the mass in the centre of the coordinate system, this means that this straight line should go through the origin, i.e. that $b=0$. Note that the only straight line not covered by the relation $y=a x$ is the line $x=0$, which coincides with the $y$-axis.

Comment: For y=ax with nonzero a, wouldn't orbits not coincide with the axes? Also, doesn't being in the xy plane of configuration space mean v is zero?

Comment: True. I have to admit I found the condition that the orbit should lie on one of the two axes a bit strange, but if this is indeed what you're looking for, then the only two straight line orbits to consider are those for which $x=0$ or $y=0$. As for the velocity being zero: no, not at all. The idea is that this object *moves* in the $x-y$ plane, with nonzero speed, otherwise no collision would occur. You might be confused between the *configuration space* and the *phase space*, see this question [http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/185612/] for more information about that.