# Further question on an existing question about: The Newtonian Central Force System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics

Still on the question: [Understanding shift to polar coordinates in the newtonian central force system of ODE's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773692/understanding-shift-to-polar-coordinates-in-the-newtonian-central-force-system-o)

The book states that $\dfrac{X}{|X|^{3}} = -\dfrac{1}{r^{2}} (\text{cos}(\theta),\text{sin}(\theta))$

why?

Comment: Why not? $X=r(\cos(θ),\sin(θ))$ and so $|X|=r$. The minus sign is then wrong, it is either on both sides or there is none.

Comment: See also [other articles dealing with a central field](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=kepler+law+gravity)